# What statistical test would be appropriate for my study?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, paired-data, ecology, intraclass-correlation, association-measure

I am looking at the difference in flow rate on composition of coarse matter.
I have set flow rate into two categories. Above and below 3700 L/s.
I have raw data that consists (grams of matter for composition) for each flow rate, which I have converted to percentages.

```
ex Data:
Flowrate         wood       algae      leaves
100.             2          3           3
6000.            1          4           6
3400.            5          1           1
```

What statistical test would be best to see how flowrate influences composition of matter?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Your table seems to give flowrates below 3700 and have more than just two possibilities of flowrate. Is that a typo? Further, why bin your flowrates into the <3700 and >3700 buckets?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing it is running a one-way MANOVA setting flowrate as a categorical predictor, with three levels. In this case, you wouldn't need to  transform matter to percentage.